# Expand UITableViewCell when size of contents changes

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uitableview, uitextview

I have a UITextView inside a static UITableViewCell constrained like this:

[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g1dJf.png)

In the viewDidLoad() method of my table view class I want to be able to change the text of the UITextView, have the UITextView change size to fit the text (I have scrolling disabled on the UITextView), and then have the UITableViewCell still be constrained as I have intended it to be. This is my attempt to do so:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.tableView.delegate = self

    self.aboutTextView.text = "Some Long String"

    //implement self sizing cells
    tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 400.0

    //set the frame of the UITextView to match the size of the text
    let fixedWidth = aboutTextView.frame.size.width
    let newSize = aboutTextView.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: fixedWidth, height: CGFloat.max))
    var newFrame = aboutTextView.frame
    newFrame.size = CGSize(width: max(newSize.width, fixedWidth), height: newSize.height)
    aboutTextView.frame = newFrame;
    //This is returning the new size correctly

    //Reload the tableview, nothing happens, text view remains the same size as in the storyboard
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Although the new frame is bigger than the default size in the storyboard, nothing happens when the tableView is reloaded. I have tried setNeedsLayout() on the UITextView with no luck as well. I also tried constraining the height of the UITextView and changing the constant of the height through an IBOutlet but then the constraints break for obvious reasons. Anybody know why my code isn't working? Any better method to do what I am trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

All the code about the row height should go in your `tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)` function. That way, whenever the table is reloaded, the code will be executed again, changing the table height.

**Edit:** I completely misunderstood what you were doing. In the storyboard, try adding constraints to the UITextView within the cell and give it a constraint on the height, and then make sure that the cell also has a height constraint slightly larger than that of the UITextView.

Comment: I put the row height code in that delegate method, and returned the IBOutlet of the static UITableViewCell. Everything was called correctly but nothing was solved.

Comment: Why are you returning an IBOutlet? You should be creating a new cll or using reuse identifier to create new cells.

Comment: It is a _static_ cell. Reuse identifier is only useful if I was going to make multiple instances of it.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood what you were doing, I changed my answer, see if it works.

Comment: you can't constrain a cell height